# How to multiple update lines using values from the same register?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following scenario:

TOS

| codigo | U_TIPO_REFERENCIA | U_PICKING_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PK | 1234 |
| 2 | PK | 5678 |

TOS_AUX

| codigo | Cod_OS | Subtitulo | U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA | U_PICKING_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Description test 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | Description test 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | Description test 3 |  |  |
| 4 | 2 | Description test 4 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | Description test 5 |  |  |
| 6 | 2 | Description test 6 |  |  |

I want to place a trigger on Table 1, that updates table 02 Description with a concat:

table 1. field 1 , ' - ',table1.field2,' - ',table2.description

My problem is how to "mention" table 2 "same line" in the concat

Here is what I have:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[atualizaPKnoUpdate] 
ON  [dbo].[TOS] 
   AFTER update
 AS 
 BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   
    declare
    @Servico int,
    @PK float,
    @TipoPK varchar(200)

    select
    @servico = codigo,
    @pk = U_PICKING_3,
    @TipoPK = U_TIPO_REFERENCIA

    FROM inserted

    UPDATE DBO.TOS_AUX
    SET U_PICKING_3 = @PK,
    U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA = @TipoPK

    WHERE
    TOS_AUX.COD_OS=@Servico
    AND TOS_AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL
    

    UPDATE DBO.TOS_AUX
    SET 
    subtitulo = CONCAT(@TipoPK,'-',@PK,' - ',--this part is missing--)

    WHERE
    TOS_AUX.COD_OS=@Servico
    
END
```

So, for

```
UPDATE TOS
SET U_TIPO_REFERENCIA = 'PV'
WHERE CODIGO = 1
```

I expect to have:

TOS

| codigo | U_TIPO_REFERENCIA | U_PICKING_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PV | 1234 |
| 2 | PK | 5678 |

TOS_AUX

| codigo | Cod_OS | Subtitulo | U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA | U_PICKING_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | PV - 1234 - Description test 1 | PV | 1234 |
| 2 | 1 | PV - 1234 - Description test 2 | PV | 1234 |
| 3 | 1 | PV - 1234 - Description test 3 | PV | 1234 |
| 4 | 2 | Description test 4 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | Description test 5 |  |  |
| 6 | 2 | Description test 6 |  |  |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Sirs"? There are women using this site as well - please ensure your language is gender neutral.

Comment: Your trigger is broken... `Inserted` can have 0-N rows, you can't assume just 1.

Comment: Dale, in this specific case, only one row is updated a time. About gender neutral, english is not my primary language... i do not know the best word for that. don't assume i just don´t want to do it ....

Comment: Regardless of whether you expect only one row to be updated at a time, you should never write a trigger this way, because if a DBA or similar does some manual corrections to the database and updates a bunch of rows at once you need your trigger to always carry out the correct action. Or throw an error and rollback the update if more than one row is updated.

Comment: As for the gender specific comment - thats why I told you :) but for this site you don't need to worry about "prettifying" your question, i.e. don't worry "Hello", "Dear all", "Thanks", just stick to the technical problem details and everyone will thank you.

Comment: understood... now i have two problems :) . my trigger and my concat...

Comment: for the number of updated rows, maybe i cloud input an IF statement, counting the number of lines of the inserted table. if count >1, change action... what do you think?

Comment: Yip, if the number of rows is greater than 1 then throw and error and rollback the transaction. That said its going to be pretty easy to solve your problem for a multi-row scenario...

Comment: anyway... can ylu help me about how to get the TOS_AUX information for the CONCAT?

Comment: I guess the real question is why would you want this anyway? Why denormalize the database? Keep only one source of truth, only one place where data is stored, and use that to create a view of the concatenated data

Comment: Your question doesn't fully make sense, you say you want to update the description, but your code appears to update 3 columns over 2 update statements. And in your sample data, `codigo` 2 doesn't appear to have updated your  `DBO.TOS_AUX` table

Comment: Charlie, the description is the only thing that is shown in the form for the user. I must have the data in both places. the columns for reporting,and everything... but i need to have this number in description, so the user can see it

Comment: Dale, codigo 2 has not updated because in my example, i updated only codigo 1

Comment: the point is:  TOS_AUX can have its own U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA U_PICKING_3 
 specific values. But if the line has nothing, it should have the TOS "general" values.

my first update tranfers TOS values ONLY for TOS_AUX that have no values

the second update, transfers the value to the description, so the users can see in the form

Comment: @DiogoRoldão Charlieface is correct, you should be able to query the information from the source without needing to maintain the same data in multiple locations. You should be able to accomplish your end goals this way.

Comment: Why *must* you have it? Why can you not query it as needed? Why keep two copies of something which need to be kept in sync

Comment: i agree with @Charlieface. But in this case.. its very important to have this in description...

Comment: @Charlieface, i have no access to the front end. and in the UI, the only field that is shown is the Description

Comment: You could make a view which the front end can access though

Comment: ^^ Yes, a `view` is a better approach.  No need for duplication or triggers. Just have the front end use the view instead of the table.  It shouldn't care as long as it receives the correct column names...

Comment: @Charlieface, i will check if i can work this out with the front end guys. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring whether or not your approach is correct for the moment, I believe you just need a `JOIN`ed `UPDATE` e.g. something similar to the following where you join the `Inserted` pseudo-table onto the table you want to update and then conditionally update as required. I have done the best I can to match your existing logic, but you'll have to test it. Note this also solves your issue of handling multiple rows being updated at the same time.

```
UPDATE AUX SET
    U_PICKING_3 = CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_PICKING_3 ELSE AUX.U_PICKING_3 END
    , U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA = CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_TIPO_REFERENCIA ELSE AUX.U_TIPO_REFERENCIA END
    , Subtitulo = CONCAT(I.U_TIPO_REFERENCIA, '-', U_PICKING_3, ' - ', AUX.Subtitulo)
FROM DBO.TOS_AUX AUX
INNER JOIN Inserted I ON I.codigo = TOS.COD_OS;
```

However for the sake of completeness, it would be remiss of me not to mention that this is most likely a bad approach. One should avoid storing the same data in multiple locations at all costs because it leads to all sorts of issues that are easily avoided by maintaining the data in a single location and querying it as required.

Comment: You should `EXCEPT` the `deleted` table (taking into account the primary key)

Comment: @Charlieface guess my brain is on slow mode today... why am I excepting the deleted table? :)

Comment: @DaleK i think i understood. Big thanks!!! and i can see how unconfortable you are for giving what you don't think it's correct. thank you for that!

Comment: Because it's an `UPDATE` trigger and there may be rows which have not actually changed, even though they were referenced in the update statement

Comment: @Charlieface ar, thanks. I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: I didn’t know the UPDATE JOIN… this is going to salve many problems. Thank You!

Comment: @DiogoRoldão the official documentation is always worth reading... you'll learn a lot that way.

Comment: @DaleK, worked like a charm. Made some minor improvements for my business rule. but thank you a lot. will post down how it became

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[atualizapknoUpdatetos] 
   ON  [dbo].[TOS] 
   AFTER update
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
UPDATE AUX SET
    U_PICKING_3 = CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_PICKING_3 ELSE AUX.U_PICKING_3 END
    , U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA = CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_TIPO_REFERENCIA ELSE AUX.U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA END
    , Subtitulo = case
    when aux.SUBTITULO like 'PK%' then aux.SUBTITULO
    when aux.SUBTITULO like 'PVK%' then aux.SUBTITULO
    else CONCAT( CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_TIPO_REFERENCIA ELSE AUX.U_TIPO_DOC_REFERENCIA END, '-', CASE WHEN AUX.U_PICKING_3 IS NULL THEN I.U_PICKING_3 ELSE AUX.U_PICKING_3 END, ' - ', AUX.Subtitulo)
    end
FROM DBO.TOS_AUX AUX
INNER JOIN Inserted I ON I.codigo = AUX.COD_OS;
END
```

Comment: please always provide explanation oh why your code works